# Is it possible to get current environment in the attribute files?

Tags: chef-infra

I would like to do something like this:

attributes/default.rb

```
if node[:chef_environment] == 'dev'
   include_attribute "mbev::dev"
else
   include_attribute "mbdev::production"
end
```

But it appears that 'node' is equal the name of the current node.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `node.chef_environment` ? It's a function which returns the value rather than an attribute.

Comment: doesn't work in recent versions of Chef (I have ChefDK 0.17.17)

Answer (score 2):

Inside an attribute file, I think you want to use just `chef_environment`, according to [this](http://lists.opscode.com/sympa/arc/chef/2014-03/msg00181.html) post in the Chef Mailing List, and independently confirmed by me.

Your attribute file should then look like this:

```
if chef_environment == 'dev'
    include_attribute "mbev::dev"
else
    include_attribute "mbdev::production"
end
```

`node.chef_environment` will work in recipes.

Comment: Was about ready to pull my hair out as we want our attributes visible in the cookbook and anytime I tried a `node.chef_environment` foodcritic failed with FC039 and I wasn't having much luck finding a way around it til this.